# How to find NGINX+ end points from a given URL

Tags: bash, nginx, nginx-config

I am automating a script for collecting some info, given a specific URL and returning all the server in the upstream Pool for that URL in a running **NGINX+** instance.

My goal is to have something that I can query on web, or a script that I can run hourly basis and create an HTML with it that I can query later with my script.

I was planning to extract the info from the *dashboard* upstreams, but unfortunately the zones aren't descriptive enough and couldn't show all the matching URL in the regex definition for **server_name** on the config files.

From this running config :

> > server {
> >     listen 443 ssl http2;
> >     listen[::]:443 ssl http2;
> >     server_name ~^(www|www2|www3).mycompany.com$;
> >     status_zone www.mycompany.com;
> >     ....    ....
> >
> > }
> >
> > upstream www {
> >     least_time
> >     header;    zone area1 128k;
> >     server server1.mycompany.com:443 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
> >     server server2.mycompany.com:443 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
> >     server server3.mycompany.com:443 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
> >
> > }

Want to get from this 
**Input URL** : www2.mycompany.com

> > these **Output Servers**: server1, server2, server3

Any Idea?